# Adding and Updating a List object does not work in C#

Tags: c#, linq

Newbie with C# and Linq.

I am trying to add an object and update an object if exists in a List. The list is not getting updated or not getting added with new inputs.It is not throwing any exception. Kindly, help.

```
private IList<SettingsEntity> Settings = new List<SettingsEntity>();

public SettingsRepository() {
            Settings.Add(new SettingsEntity() { UserID = "alpha", ApplicationName = "protocol archive", SettingKey = "RefreshTime", SettingValue = "20", UpdatedOn = new DateTime().Date, SettingLabel = "RefreshInterval", IsActive = true });
            Settings.Add(new SettingsEntity() { UserID = "bravo", ApplicationName = "view", SettingKey = "RefreshRate", SettingValue = "10", UpdatedOn = new DateTime().Date, SettingLabel = "RefreshInterval", IsActive = true });
            Settings.Add(new SettingsEntity() { UserID = "charlie", ApplicationName = "upload", SettingKey = "RefreshTime", SettingValue = "20", UpdatedOn = new DateTime().Date, SettingLabel = "RefreshInterval", IsActive = true });
            Settings.Add(new SettingsEntity() { UserID = "foxtrot", ApplicationName = "protocol archive", SettingKey = "RefreshTime", SettingValue = "20", UpdatedOn = new DateTime().Date, SettingLabel = "RefreshInterval", IsActive = true });
            Settings.Add(new SettingsEntity() { UserID = "lima", ApplicationName = "view", SettingKey = "RefreshTime", SettingValue = "20", UpdatedOn = new DateTime().Date, SettingLabel = "RefreshInterval", IsActive = true });
            Settings.Add(new SettingsEntity() { UserID = "Julie", ApplicationName = "upload", SettingKey = "RefreshTime", SettingValue = "20", UpdatedOn = new DateTime().Date, SettingLabel = "RefreshInterval", IsActive = true });
            Settings.Add(new SettingsEntity() { UserID = "tango", ApplicationName = "protocol archive", SettingKey = "RefreshTime", SettingValue = "20", UpdatedOn = new DateTime().Date, SettingLabel = "RefreshInterval", IsActive = true });
            Settings.Add(new SettingsEntity() { UserID = "victor", ApplicationName = "protocol archive", SettingKey = "RefreshTime", SettingValue = "20", UpdatedOn = new DateTime().Date, SettingLabel = "RefreshInterval", IsActive = true });
            Settings.Add(new SettingsEntity() { UserID = "yankee", ApplicationName = "protocol archive", SettingKey = "RefreshTime", SettingValue = "20", UpdatedOn = new DateTime().Date, SettingLabel = "RefreshInterval", IsActive = true });
            Settings.Add(new SettingsEntity() { UserID = "zulu", ApplicationName = "protocol archive", SettingKey = "RefreshTime", SettingValue = "20", UpdatedOn = new DateTime().Date, SettingLabel = "RefreshInterval", IsActive = true });
        }

 public bool Save(SettingsEntity entity)
        {
            var flag = false;
            if (entity != null)
            {
                var existing = Settings.Where(se => se.UserID == entity.UserID && se.ApplicationName == entity.ApplicationName && se.SettingKey == entity.SettingKey).ToList();
                if (existing != null)
                {
                    existing.ForEach(f => f.SettingValue = entity.SettingValue);
                    flag = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    Settings.Add(entity);
                    flag = true;
                }
                return flag;
            }
            else {
                throw new ArgumentNullException();
            }


        }

 [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Post([FromBody] SettingsEntity entity)
        {
            var result = _SettingsRepository.Save(entity);
            if (result == true)
            {
                return Ok();
            }
            else
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Where do you  call Save()?

Comment: @Sajeetharan add the caller method

Comment: What is `Settings`?

Comment: While debugging, and trying to add a new SettingsEntitty did it hit the line Settings.Add() in the else{} block? if Yes, what did you see in the Settings object there?

Comment: I don't think `existing` will ever be `null`. It might be empty, but not `null`.

Comment: Why did you decide that the update does not work?

Comment: @germi is right, `existing` will never be set to null.

Comment: The add/update should work, but in case you are not using singleton repository, the list will simply be recreated.

Comment: Use FirstOrDefault instead of ToList extension method.

Comment: Put a breakpoint before `return flag;` and check while debug if the List has been changed. I'm sure that it has been updated but as @IvanStoev has written it's being recreated for every request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
var existing = Settings.Where(se => se.UserID == entity.UserID 
                                 && se.ApplicationName == entity.ApplicationName 
                                 && se.SettingKey == entity.SettingKey).ToList();
```

will never be `null`.

Therefore your `Settings.Add(entity)` will never be called. Instead of testing for `null` you could write

```
if (existing.Any()) //or if (existing.Count > 0)
{ 
    ... 
} 
else 
{ 
    //Save here 
}
```

Comment: There's also another approach: you could implement `IComparable` interface, so it would decide if the entities are the same based on the given rule. Then you could achieve the above easily.

Comment: @MichałTurczyn true, though that would still have returned the same - empty - list

Answer (score 0):

Linq queries always return Ienumerable collection which either has zero or more than zero elements. So, It will never be null. Moreover, you can skip the flag variable too. By putting a count check to ensure that something has been added or not.

Or try to avoid using Count method. As it has complexity of o(n). So, if you just want to ensure is there any item, then prefer to use Any() method instead of Count();

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't this work for you? The `List` you tried to get will never be null (how could it? You got it from a valid `IEnumerable`) so what you can do is check the number of elements in the `List`.

Btw. you will always return `true`, so I removed that to make your code more readable.

```
public void Save(SettingsEntity entity)
{
    if (entity == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException();

    var existing = Settings.Where(se => se.UserID == entity.UserID && se.ApplicationName == entity.ApplicationName && se.SettingKey == entity.SettingKey).ToList();
    if (existing.Count > 0)
        existing.ForEach(f => f.SettingValue = entity.SettingValue);
    else
        Settings.Add(entity);
}
```